# "Many of the young people" or "many young people"

Tags: exam-questions

> Many of the young people studying abroad agreed that returning home was always an attractive option.

Is the *of the* used in the sentence correct? It sounds better to me without using *of the*, i.e.:

> *Many young people studying abroad agreed that returning home was always an attractive option.*

If it is correct, what is the difference in the meaning of two sentences, if any?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Many **of the young people** studying abroad...

means that if you had a defined group of young people, *some* of them agreed that...

> Many **young people** studying abroad...

just refers to a (relatively) large quantity of young people.

Both are possible, but more context is needed to decide which is appropriate. We don't know if the "young people" are a defined group, nor can you quantify them.